# How to write in mathematical symbols the expression "range over"

Tags: article-writing

My question is really simple, how can I write symbolically this phrase:

> $x=\sum a_mx^m$ where $m$ range over
>   $\{1,\ldots,g\}\setminus\{t_1,\ldots,t_u\}$

Being more specific, I would like to know how to write with mathematical symbols this part: "range over $\{1,\ldots,g\}\setminus\{t_1,\ldots,t_u\}$"

Thanks

Comment: $\Large\in.\mbox{}$

Comment: @FelixMarin I think it doesn't work, because, $m\in \{1,\ldots,g\}\setminus\{t_1,\ldots,t_u\}$ means there is only one $m$, no?.

Answer (score 2):

Often we see something like$$x=\sum_{m\in\{1,\ldots,g\}\setminus\{t_1,\ldots,t_u\}} a_mx^m$$

Comment: I don't have space to write this expression below the sum symbol, do you have another suggestion? thanks

Comment: You could define a set $A=\{{ 1,\ldots,g\}\setminus\{t_1,\ldots,t_u\}}$, then $m \in A$ under the sum

Comment: The truth is the expression I would like to write is more complex, I still prefer not write symbols under the sum. Do you have some suggestion to write _after_ the sum symbol? thanks again.

Comment: I think I have seen the $m \in$ stuff on the line with the sum sign, out to the right after the expression to add.  This has the advantage that your reader won't have to look back for the definition of $A$.  If the expression you are summing is long, you may run out of space there as well.

Comment: Do you think this work: $x=\sum a_mx^m$,where $m\in \{1,\ldots,g\}\setminus\{t_1,\ldots,t_u\}$?

Comment: I think that would be clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest
$$\Large x=\sum_{\substack{m=1\\[0.1cm] m\,\notin\, \{t_1,\,\ldots\,,\,t_u\}}}^g a_mx^m$$

Comment: This is better than mine if $1,\dots g$ are contiguous.

Comment: I don't have space to write this expression below the sum symbol, do you have another suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could put the limits of the sum behind the sum, making them ore inline instead of the big displaystyle format.

If you are using LaTeX I do wonder why there is no space left to use the slightly better looking alternative Kez gave. (if you are not using LaTeX, why not..?)

$\Large x=\sum_{{m=1\ldots g,\,\, m\,\notin\, \{t_1,\,\ldots\,,\,t_u\}}} a_mx^m$